# How to make polymorphic Form that accept any type of form values with `react-hook-form`

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I created a Form component using `react-hook-form` library and I'm trying to make it polymorphic. But I'm having some typescript errors.

Here's what the component looks like:

```js
type FormProps<T> = {
  defaultValues: T;
  onSubmit: (data: T) => void;
  children: ({ control, register }: Partial<UseFormReturn>) => ReactNode;
};

function Form<T>({ defaultValues, onSubmit, children }: FormProps<T>) {
  const { handleSubmit, register } = useForm({ defaultValues })
                                            // ^^^^ error:

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>{children({ register })}</form>
                              // ^^^^ error             ^^^^ error
  );
}
```

The errors are:

1. defaultValues: `Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'UnpackNestedValue<DeepPartial<T>>'`
2. onSubmit: `'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'UnpackNestedValue<T>'`
3. register: `'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'FieldValues'.`

I can fix the first error by changing `defaultValues` type from `T` to `UnpackNestedValue<DeepPartial<T>>` but I'm not sure if it's the way to go.

I also don't understand what to do with the second and third error.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-sky-yycgos?file=/src/Form.tsx
If you guys could help me out I'd really appreciate it

## upd

```js
type FormProps<T extends FieldValues> = {
  defaultValues?: DefaultValues<T>;
  onSubmit: (data: UnpackNestedValue<T>) => void;
  children: ReactNode | (({ register, formState }: FormChildrenProps<T>) => ReactNode);
};
export const Form = <T,>({ defaultValues, onSubmit, children }: FormProps<T>) => {
  const { handleSubmit, register, formState } = useForm({ defaultValues });

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      {typeof children === 'function' ? children({ register, formState }) : children}
    </form>
  );
};
```

If anyone know a better way please let me know =)